# angular.js change url without calling controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, pushstate

I have to fix such solution:
my url is `http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard` in my dashboard there are some features to load, for example when my url will be `http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard/20` I must load cities which country id equals 20 and when my url will be `http://localhost:8080/#/dashboard/20/1` I have to load districts which city id equals 1. so what is my problem:
    when I click some links and url changes to `#/dashboard/20` I am loading cities, after that I click another one link and url changes to `#/dashboard/20/1` but here my controller is refreshing and all data is loading again, I want to change url but not refreshing controller, when my cities are already loaded I must have opportunity to load only districts after that and not both of them again at once.

I tried `window.history.pushState` but it does not work, may be is there any way to disable and enable my `$routeProvider`?

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see this working is referring to the same controller or using a factory/service to maintain your variables.
The controllers will always change when the state changes if they are glued to them.

Edit: Btw, have you taken a look at ui.router? https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
Here's the link. I find this much more helpful than the old $route